# regular expression for matching "|>" symbols in java

Tags: java, regex

I have following lines of string in a file.

`|>XYZ|8489<|`

`|>Abc|673<|`

`|>tzu|2873<|`

I need to filter the lines which matches with the pattern like it should starts with `|>XYZ`  or `|>tzu` and ends with `<|`. In other words it should return the first and the third line.

Can anyone please suggest me how to do it with regex in Java?

Comment: By writing a regex that matches them? You'll need to escape the | characters with a double backslash: "\\|".

Comment: Do you really need to match a `"` at the beginning?  (And not at the end?)  I removed that on the theory that you were using as an actual quote, like you did in the title.

Comment: You are correct. I dont need to match `"` in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^("\|>)(XYZ|tzu).*(<\|)$
```

or in Java

```
^("\\|>)(XYZ|tzu).*(<\\|)$
```

^ - Start of line

$ - end of line

(XYZ|tzu) = Either XYZ or tzu

("\|>) = matches ">

(<\|) = matches <|

Comment: The double backslash is necessary because the regex is written in the form of a Java string literal.  If you're going to use them, you should include the enclosing quotes, and you should escape the quote that's part of the regex: "^(\"\\|>)(XYZ|tzu).*(<\\|)$"

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
^"[|]>(XYZ|tzu).*?<[|]$
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/wF0vC8

Comment: Why `[|]` and not just `\|`?

Comment: @fge Question is tagged as Java so it should have been `\\|` but somehow for me too many of those backslashes make it difficult to read.

Comment: It is `\\|` _only when in a Java string_. The canonical form is `\|`.